# Running bash does "segmentation fault core dumped"

Tags: bash, segmentation-fault

I rebooted recently, and now terminal fails to work. If I click the terminal shortcut or use `Guake` or `ctrl-alt-T`, the terminal opens briefly with no prompt, then immediately closes again. I installed `xterm` as well and the same thing happens.

If I use `ctrl-alt-F1` to get to a command line session and type `gnome-terminal` I get the error message:

```
Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display
```

How can I diagnose and fix this?

EDIT TO ADD `.bashrc`

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile"

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"
alias zf=/home/julio/ZendFramework-1.12.3/bin/zf.sh
```

EDIT 2-- adding `.profile`:

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

export SCALA_HOME=/usr/share/scala
export PATH=$PATH:$SCALA_HOME/bin
source ~/.profile
```

Comment: Please post the contents of your `$HOME/.bashrc` and `$HOME/.xsession-errors` files.

Comment: Can you please run sudo apt-get remove gnome-terminal then sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal and then try again

Comment: Hmm, that looks fine, could you also post your `$HOME/.profile` if you have it? Also, please try `ctrl-alt-f1` then login, then run `bash`. Do you get any error messages? Do _not_ try running `gnome-terminal` that's a graphical program and will fail with the exact message (`Cannot open display`) in your question, that has nothing to do with your issue. Did you try launching `xterm` or just install it?

Comment: uninstall / reinstall did not fix the issue.

Comment: @terdon-- I ran `bash` and got the message `segmentation fault core dumped` -- I did try running `xterm` and it failed the same way the `gnome-terminal` did.

Comment: what version of ubuntu are you running?

Comment: It's Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: ^ @terdon how to do this "Removing the source ~/.profile line from your ~/.profile" ??

Comment: @mayank well, you open the file `$HOME/.profile` in a text editor and delete the line that says `source ~/.profile` from the file if such a line is there.

Comment: @terdon i viewed all the files that u have mentioned but none of them have any of those two line.

Comment: @user3667696 yes, well, they're not supposed to. This is just the particular problem that user101289 had. There is no reason to expect your files would have that line since that line breaks your system. If you have a new problem, please post a new question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `gnome-terminal`, when you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>F1</kbd>, logged in from the virtual console and tried running `bash`, you got a `segmentation fault core dumped` which means that `bash` itself crashes.

Anyway, what's happening is that your bash is entering an infinite loop. When `bash` first starts, it reads `~/.bashrc` (actually, this is a simplification, see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38175/22222) for more details). In your case (and in most if not all Ubuntu versions), the default `.bashrc`, for reasons that have never been clear to me, sources (reads) `~/.profile` as well. Now, your `~/.profile` includes this line:

```
source ~/.profile
```

The result of that is that `bash` reads `~/.bashrc` => reads `~/.profile` => reads `~/.profile` => reads `~/.profile` => reads `~/.profile` etc. This is called an endless loop. Eventually, it freaks out and crashes.

Removing the `source ~/.profile` line from your `~/.profile` should set everything back to normal.

Comment: @terdon-- that sounded like the ticket, but I removed the line, saved the file and rebooted-- same issue.

Comment: @user101289 strange. Check the file again, is the line still there?  If not, we're going to have to check all of your bash initialization files, post the _full_ contents of each of `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.profile`, `~./bashrc`, `~/bash_login`, `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `/etc/profile`. If any of these don't exist, don't worry about it, that's normal, just post the rest. Feel free to @ ping me in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room).

Comment: @terndon-- thanks for your help! It appears that there was a similar line saying `#[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile"` in `.bashrc`-- I commented that out and I'm back in business!

Answer (score 0):

For mayank

"Removing the source ~/.profile line from your ~/.profile" means just searching for the files ~/.bash_profile, ~/.profile, ~./bashrc, ~/bash_login, /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile (as mentioned in comment), opening them and removing the line:

```
source ~/.profile
```

or

```
#[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile
```

FYI: '~' is not a strange symbol, it just means your home directory. so its basically the path of .profile file.

```
Its HOME_DIRECTORY/.profile.
```